# Github test badge from TeamCity build test results

Tags: teamcity, badge, github-flavored-markdown, readme

I'm attempting to get my **TeamCity** build server's test results to show up as a badge in the **GitHub** repository's `README.md` file.  I was able to get the build status badge to show up and work as desired, but I cannot find any examples of this working for the test results. Is this possible, if so can someone please help me out?